# PHP switch array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very simple array like this:

```
Array ( [friend_id] => 180 [user_id] => 175 )
```

What I want to do is just to switch the values, in order to be come this:

```
Array ( [friend_id] => 175 [user_id] => 180 )
```

Is there any elegant NON STATIC way in PHP to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "non static"?

Comment: By non-static, do you mean that you always want the `friend_id` switched with the `user_id`?

Comment: No I mean that it can do the job without having to declare the indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
$swapped = array_combine(array_keys($arr), array_reverse(array_values($arr)));
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Use a temporary value:

```
$temp = $array['friend_id'];
$array['friend_id'] = $array['user_id'];
$array['user_id'] = $temp;
```

Comment: Odd, imo this answer is as wrong as the one scoring -1, yet it gets 2 upvotes.

Comment: @fvu: uh, perhaps you should start looking at timestamps. at the time I posted this, the OP hadn't yet posted his "without indexes" comment.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, I was merely commenting on what I perceive as intriguing voting behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A bit longish, but I think it satisfies you requirements for 2 element arrays, just as you used in your example:

```
// your input array = $yourarray;
$keyarray = array_keys($yourarray);
$valuearray = array_values($yourarray);
/// empty input array just to make sure
$yourarray = array();
$yourarray[$keyarray[0]] = $valuearray[1];
$yourarray[$keyarray[1]] = $valuearray[0];
```

Basically Orangepill's answer done manually...

Answer (score 0):

How about using array_flip?

> array array_flip ( array $trans )

```
$myar = array('apples', 'oranges', 'pineaples');                                   print_r($myar);                                                                   
print_r(array_flip($myar));      
Array
(
    [0] => apples
    [1] => oranges
    [2] => pineaples
)
Array
(
    [apples] => 0
    [oranges] => 1
    [pineaples] => 2
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$tmp = $array['user_id'];
$array['user_id'] = $array['friend_id'];
$array['friend_id'] = $tmp;
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but in his clarification OP says you don't know the indexes.  Your technique only works when the indexes are known.